# `multiprocessing.Process` are modifying non-shared variables they should not have access to

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Processes are mutating things they should not be able to mutate.

A `Worker`has a single state variable (an `mp.Value`). This value is set to `-1`, and it (the `Worker`) changes it to `1` in a loop.

However, it seems to be possible to reset that value **back** to `-1` by spawning a second `Worker`, even though this shares nothing with the original pair. This seems like it should be impossible.

**Behavior:**

When the second `Worker` spins up, the state of the first worker (`self.state.value` ) gets reset to `-1`. This gets caught, and we print out that an error was discovered.

**Code:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, tag, service_state) -> None:
        self.tag = tag
        self.local_state = int(service_state.value)
        self.state = service_state
        self.run_work_loop()

    def run_work_loop(self) -> None:
        print(f"[{self.tag}] Running... {self.state.value} {self.local_state}")
        while True:
            if self.state.value != self.local_state:
                print(f"[{self.tag}] Illegal change. Shared state: {self.state.value} Local State: {self.local_state}")
                break

            elif self.state.value == -1:
                self.state.value = self.local_state = 1
                print(f"[{self.tag}] Set Shared State: {self.state.value} Local State: {self.local_state}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("A", mp.Value('i', -1))).start()
    time.sleep(.03)
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("B", mp.Value('i', -1))).start()
```

**Output:**

```
[A] Running... -1 -1
[A] Set Shared State: 1 Local State: 1.
[A] Illegal change. Shared state: -1 Local State: 1
[B] Running... -1 -1
[B] Set Shared State: 1 Local State: 1.
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is related to not keeping a reference to the `Value`s in the main process.  That completely defeats the purpose of using a shared object, anyway.

Comment: @jasonharper correct - if you save the first `mp.Value` to a local variable, and pass that to `args`, the issue goes away. Not exactly sure why, but I think both the `mp.Value` instances end up pointing to the same thing when they are directly passed into `args`.

Comment: I think it has to do with the way `multiprocessing.Value` gets allocated. Internally it's allocating memory using `ctypes` for the `Value`. I suspect because the `mp.Value` goes out of scope in the parent process when you pass it directly to `args`, the same memory location  is getting reused when you create the second `Value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating `Value` instances that immediately go out of scope in the parent process, which makes them get garbage collected. Because [of the way Python allocates memory for `multiprocessing.Value` objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L44), the second `Value` ends up using the exact same shared memory location as the first `Value`, which means the second ends up stomping on the first. You can do some experiments to see this in action. For example, this does not print the warning:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("A", mp.Value('i', -1))).start()
    time.sleep(.03)
    a = mp.Value('i', 1)
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("B", mp.Value('i', -1))).start()
```

The `Value` we assign to `a` is initialized to 1, which overwrites the anonymous `Value` we passed to process "A". Because we overwrite it with 1, no illegal state message is printed. if we instead initialize it to any other value, you will see the warning again. This prints an illegal state message about -2, , for example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("A", mp.Value('i', -1))).start()
    time.sleep(.03)
    a = mp.Value('i', -2)
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("B", mp.Value('i', -1))).start()
```

Your code should really save the `Value` instances you create as local variables in your parent process, both to avoid this issue, and because it's pointless to create shared values that you don't actually share. Like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = mp.Value('i', -1)
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("A", a)).start()
    time.sleep(.03)
    b = mp.Value('i', -1)
    mp.Process(target=Worker, args=("B", b)).start()
```

Comment: You can verify this is in fact the problem by adding an `import ctypes` to the top of the file, and adding `print(f"[{self.tag}] Address of service_state storage: {ctypes.addressof(service_state._obj):#x}")` just before calling `self.run_work_loop()`. Both child processes report their independently constructed `mp.Value`s have their underlying storage at the same location. Checking source code, `Process.start` intentionally `del`s the `target`, `args` and `kwargs` provided just after the child process is spawned, before `start` returns; the refcnt isn't cross process, so it's cleaned then.

Comment: I think a safer solution would be to hold on to the `mp.Value`s in the parent (`v1, v2 = mp.Value('i', -1), mp.Value('i', -1)`, then pass `v1` to the first `Process` and `v2` to the second, rather than making fake `mp.Value`s just to reclaim the memory (there's no guarantee sequential allocate/deallocate/allocate operations will actually get the same memory twice after all, but if you hold on to the memory, it's definitely not reused). It's rather odd to make shared `mp.Value`s that aren't actually shared after all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the code sample isn't intended to be a solution, it's just demonstrating what's happening. Of course the right thing to do is to save the Values to a local variable! I will update my answer to make that clear